# Is it possible to limit YAML bool value literal in python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using YAML to describe some configuration that will be read by a Python tool using `ruamel`. The problem is I need to use string literal ON a lot and in YAML ON without quote will be treated as bool value `true`. I have to quote those 'ON' carefully or else the tool will throw unexpected result.

Is it possible to tell `ruamel` to only treat `true` and `false` as bool, and for other keywords like ON, Yes, just treat them as string literal to reduce the chance of making mistake? For this use case I don't think I have to stick to the YAML specification as there is little chance that the configuration file will be processed by others.

Comment: It seems your approach would not reduce the chance of making mistakes but hide the mistakes instead.

Comment: The yaml configuration file will only be used by this very specific tool so I guess I don't need to care about how the other parsers will handle.  I just want to create a `yaml dialect` for my toolset.

Comment: `On` has been removed as boolean from the YAML 1.2 specifications released in 2009. This one of the few (small) changes compared to YAML 1.1, so if a tool/library still has not caught up after 13+ years, it is probably never going to.

Comment: Fair enough. I did not mean to invalidate the question as a whole. It's just whenever I read "I want my app to do the right thing when the input is wrong" I raise an eyebrow. I can see I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using `ruamel.yaml` and not some of the other packages in the ruamel. namespace.
Without some code it is difficult to see what you are doing wrong, but if you use the default
loader you'll get a string for loading `On` or `on`.

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- True
- On
- on
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
[True, 'On', 'on']
```

If your document has a `%YAML 1.1` directive, or set `yaml.version = (1, 1), then` On will be read as boolean:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- True
- On
- on
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.version = (1, 1)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
[True, True, True]
```

Comment: Thanks! It is the header `%YAML 1.1` !  It's OK after I remove the line. But `vscode` still have wrong syntax highlight, is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I don't use vscode so I have no idea. YAML formatters/highlighters are not of high quality in my experience. Especially not if you have a sequence or literal style scalar at the root level of you document.